# XMPPFramework Swift Compiler Error after update to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xmppframework

I'm converting Swift 2.3 to Swift 3 branch:
When I convert swift 3 "Swift Compiler Error" : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

happen in my project.

I use this pod file :

pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

How to solve this problem?. Please help me.

Comment: Don't use Swift ;) But seriously, did you try converting your project instead the complete workspace?

Comment: Yes! I converting my project instead the complete workspace. Why not I use  swift. It's is suitable for me. @JulianF.Weinert

Comment: Hmm... Sorry, no more ideas. Why not? It's my personal opinion about it. It's not mature enough to be used professionally. I didn't see any big Swift project that didn't need to use ObjC because something is still missing. Every time I open an older project, I need to fix stuff because the new compiler doesn't support the old language. The language itself is not logical to me and resolves many issues the stupid way. Compare the function (/method-) naming with ObjC – isn't Swift crap? But hey, that's my personal view. Sorry, can't help here

Comment: I'ts ok bro. Thanks for your opinion. @JulianF.Weinert

Comment: There's not really enough context to go on here.  Can you post the code that's causing the issue?  And more of the actual error message?